# How to install "HTML Property Editor"?

Tags: devexpress

I created the project "eXpressApp Framework" using the "Solution Wizard".
I used the following settings:

Choose the Target Platforms:
- Windows;
Choose the ORM:
- eXpress Persistent Objects;
Choose the Authentication Type:
- None;

Choose Extra Modules:
- Workflow;
- HTML Property Editor;
- Tree List Editors;

When I run the application, the window is only "Workflow".

How to connect "HTML Property Editor"?
I want to see how the "HTML Property Editor" works.
How can I do this?

**image** :
[image: **image**]

Comment: Inline image; trademark capitalization; grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go through documentation:
[HTML Property Editor Module](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113140/Concepts/Extra-Modules/HTML-Property-Editor/HTML-Property-Editor-Module)
[How to: Apply HTML Formatting to Windows Forms XAF UI Elements](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113130/Task-Based-Help/Application-Model/How-to-Apply-HTML-Formatting-to-Windows-Forms-XAF-UI-Elements)

> To construct a Windows Forms UI, XAF uses controls from the
> XtraEditors Suite. XAF supports the capability of certain controls
> from this Suite to format the display text using Hyper Text Markup
> Language (HTML). This document lists what XAF UI elements support HTML
> formatting, and provides you with the examples of using this feature.
>
> The following XAF UI elements support HTML Formatting:
>
> - Static Text View Item's text.
> - Property Editor's captions in Detail Views.
> - Column captions of the Windows Forms GridListEditor.
>
> By default, XAF uses this List Editor to visualize List Views in
> Windows Forms applications.

To know about the string properties check this:
[String Properties](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113528/Concepts/Business-Model-Design/Data-Types-Supported-by-built-in-Editors/String-Properties)

Hope this help.

Comment: I read it.
Sorry, but I do not understand where I can see how the "HTML Property Editor Module" works.

Could you please write in more detail what I should do to see the text editor as in the picture "https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113140/Concepts/Extra-Modules/HTML-Property-Editor/HTML-Property- Editor-Module "

Comment: check [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113528/Concepts/Business-Model-Design/Data-Types-Supported-by-built-in-Editors/String-Properties)

Comment: @user9776818, if you are new to XAF, you need to follow [tutorials](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113577/Getting-Started). Otherwise, none of the documentation articles will be helpful without understanding the basic principles.